# Process that can sleep waiting for a tty driver protocol RX

Tags: c, linux, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

My aim is to have a user space linux process that sleep while a tty uart based driver is receiving a message.

The protocol is a very simple (bad) stream of data that starts with a break signal followed by 513 bytes.

So far I modified the freescale's tty uart driver interrupt to receive the message.

```
static int DMX_RX(struct imx_port *sport)
{
    struct tty_port *port = &sport->port.state->port;

    tty_flip_buffer_push(port);

    struct uart_state *state = sport->port.state;
    if (sport->port.flags & UPF_SAK)
        do_SAK(state->port.tty);
    return 0;
}

static irqreturn_t imx_rxint(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    struct imx_port *sport = dev_id;
    unsigned int rx, flg, ignored = 0;
    struct tty_port *port = &sport->port.state->port;
    unsigned long flags, temp;

    spin_lock_irqsave(&sport->port.lock, flags);

    while (readl(sport->port.membase + USR2) & USR2_RDR)
    {
        flg = TTY_NORMAL;
        sport->port.icount.rx++;

        rx = readl(sport->port.membase + URXD0);

        temp = readl(sport->port.membase + USR2);
        if (temp & USR2_BRCD)
        {
            writel(USR2_BRCD, sport->port.membase + USR2);
            // Break received then push the message to userspace
            DMX_RX(sport);
        }
        else
        {
            // Byte received then put it in the flip buffer
            tty_insert_flip_char(port, rx, flg);
        }

        .....
        // other stuff
        .....

out:
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&sport->port.lock, flags);
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

Then I implemented a simple process on linux user space as below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/termios.h>
#include <sched.h>

int ioctl(int d, int request, ...);

#define MAX_DATA_LOG 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct termios2 t;
    int fd,baud;
    char buf[513];    
    fd = open("/dev/ttyDMXc4", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    baud = 250000;

    if (ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, &t))
    {
        perror("TCGETS2");
        return 3;
    }

    t.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;
    t.c_cflag |= BOTHER;
    t.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;
    t.c_ospeed = baud;

    t.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | ECHO);
                            /* Noncanonical mode, disable signals, extended
                               input processing, and echoing */

    t.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | IGNBRK | IGNCR | INLCR |
                      INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | PARMRK);
                        /* Disable special handling of CR, NL, and BREAK.
                           No 8th-bit stripping or parity error handling.
                           Disable START/STOP output flow control. */

    t.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;                /* Disable all output processing */


    if (ioctl(fd, TCSETS2, &t))
    {
        perror("TCSETS2");
        return 4;
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, &t))
    {
        perror("TCGETS2");
        return 5;
    }

    printf("actual speed reported %d\n", t.c_ospeed);

    typedef struct {
        unsigned long time;
        unsigned int res;
    }stuct_appo;

    int ret = 1;
    int res;
    int i;
    fd_set read_fds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int data_log_idx=1;

    stuct_appo data_log[MAX_DATA_LOG];

    struct timespec now;

    while (1)
    {
        tv.tv_sec = 1;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        FD_SET(fd, &read_fds);

        ret = select (fd+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (ret > 0)
        {
            res = read (fd, buf, 513);

            if (res > 0)
            {
                clock_gettime(0, &now);
                data_log[data_log_idx].time = now.tv_nsec;
                data_log[data_log_idx].res = res;
                data_log_idx = (data_log_idx % MAX_DATA_LOG) + 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int i;
            printf("TIMEOUT %d!!!\n", ret);

            for (i=1; i<data_log_idx; i++)
                printf("%lu\n", data_log[i].time);
            for (i=1; i<data_log_idx; i++)
                printf("%d\n", data_log[i].res);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the select has a 1 sec of timeout.

I start my process and after receiving some messages I stop the sender and the process printout timings and received char.

What I can see is that sometimes (very often) select return and the read: eg 69 bytes. 
At the end all 513 bytes are read, but shared on 2 or 3 read, eg: 154 and 359 bytes.
I'm sure that driver push data of split buffer each 513 bytes, so my doubt is:

1. Is select awaking at the wrong time when the flip buffer is not pushed?
2. Is the read function that can read less that the whole buffer even if I specified 513 in the third parameter?

Comment: `read` can always return fewer bytes than requested.

Comment: If `select` returns with a descriptor set in the read set, it only guarantees that you can call `read` without `read` blocking. It doesn't know how much you can read. If your packet size is fixed, then you need to read in a loop until all data has been received.

Comment: @ JoachimPileborg @JonathonReinhart Thank you. Reading your comment it seems that the best way is to implement a new char driver that suspend readers with `wait_event_interruptible` and unlock them with `wake_up_interruptible` when a message is received. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable from similar drivers I ever looked at.

Comment: I will argue that it depends. I'm personally more inclined to move as much processing as possible out of the kernel and into user-space, and keep the driver as simple as possible, without any knowledge about the of the data being sent or received and leave the protocol handling to the user-space code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree with you, but the reason I want to do this at kernel level is that this protocol gives also the sync at my system (a message each 30-40 msec). Then I need to be faster as possible receiving and keeping the real "time stamp" of bus. For that reason I'm using a full preempt kernel. Take notes that is an uart (RS485) bus based. Anyway the protocol parsing will be performed by user space.